# Can we change yarn audit function to ignore a specific vulnerability?

Tags: yarnpkg

Can we change yarn audit function to ignore a specific vulnerability? Or Specify to not check on devdependecies?

Comment: you can keep the audit to happen only for dependencies only using this `yarn audit --groups dependencies`. It will ignore any `devDependencies` having audit issues.